# Bottom div not moving when top div changes height

Tags: html, css

I inserted tabs into a Wordpress theme and they are made of divs of different heights. When navigating from one tab to another, a few of the divs below follow the height of the tabs (moving up or down).
The footer doesn't move and I don't understand it.
Here is my website:
http://www.liveaerosmith.com/1973-03-20/
You can try by navigation the tabs INFO, SETLIST and FILES. Why is the footer staying put?

Comment: It seems that each of the two columns within `.row` is set to a fixed pixel height upon page load, so the footer will stay that distance below the row unless those values are updated or removed.

Comment: I suggest you find out which script is setting the height and why it's is being set. It's probably for a reason, and you could get into a rats nest of hacks if you just try to overwrite or remove it blindly.

Comment: I already did that and remove the script and will follow your sugestion about the border line.

Comment: Ok sounds good. By the way, that was ether's idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fixed height set on the two columns on the page. If you remove this pixel height, the footer will adjust as you change the tabs.

try adding this to your css:

```
.col-md-8, .col-md-4{
    height: unset !important;
}
```

Comment: Why not just remove the code that sets the heights in the first place?

Comment: @showdev because I don't know how the height is set. Best solution I could  provide with the limited information available.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed height on `col-md-8`.

```
.col-md-8{
    height: 944px;
}
```

You footer is directly up against the bottom of this element, but by setting a fixed height, it doesn't allow the `col-md-8` to rescale based on the content within.

Comment: col-md-8 doesn't have a fixed height, its height is somehow generated when the page is loaded so that the grey lines align perfectly. If you load the page with the browser at a different size (not fullscreen, for instance), you will see the col-md-8 height is different. I need to change that behavior someway.

Comment: In that case, recalculating the heights seems more appropriate. If the heights are set in order to keep grey lines aligned, won't overwriting the heights defeat that purpose?

Comment: @showdev He could always do the above and set `height: unset`, then switch the border to the right-side of this container. That way it's border will always be as tall as the container.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will switch the border to the right side of the left container and adjust paddings accordingly!